# Altium Grid Ends?

Tags: altium

I am trying to edit the shape of my board in Altium, and I have found that the grid simply stops at the current board edge.

I can make the board smaller, but not bigger. The cursor simply won't move beyond the current board edge.

I have no idea how to fix this and googling hasn't turned anything up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue before. I've solved it by moving the whole board design some amount from the edge.

Ensure everything is selected and then Edit -> Move -> Move Selection by X,Y. Enter some large whole number (10000 mil, for example) for your X and Y coordinates depending on which/edge corner of the grid you are running into. I'm assuming you're hitting the bottom left corner, so use positive X and Y numbers.

You will need to repour your polygons, and you will also have to move your board shape in the board planning mode separately.

Comment: I had to do this the other day and was surprised to find the board shape moved itself to match. No idea if there are some conditions where this happens and others where it doesn't.

Comment: I’ve also had this happen, but not in Altium 19 (I think). The fix is to move everything away from that edge (which is probably a hard limit in the software), then setting your origin point back to someplace useful.